# Autofilling multiple cells using multiple locations

Tags: excel

I currently have a House Keeping (HK) sheet that is distributed to the girls when they come in. To save time in the morning, I have been trying to input a formula that automatically transfers all the rooms from the Head HK sheet to the individual HK's sheets. Currently the head HK sheet looks like this but with out the dashes:

```
Housekeeper ---------- Room --------- Status ------ Set Up

Katie ------------------ 1 ---------- Ready ------- Double

Sue -------------------- 2 ------ Departing ------- Single

Katie ------------------ 3 ------ Stay over ------- Family
```

This continues to room 43

I would like to use the HK's name as the primary data source so when I select their name (using a drop down) on the individual HK sheets it automatically fills in all the cells below associated to her in Room order.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial for how to do this, let me know if you have any questions:

http://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/947848-lookup-a-value-and-return-multiple-results.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single sheet with all the information, and you would like to create an "extract" for each girl in turn, you have at least two options

1) If you just need to print out each HK's sheet once, use the "Autofilter" option on the main sheet, then hit "Print" - and repeat for each housekeeper. It still involves a bit of work (although with just 43 rooms, and maybe a handful of housekeepers, it's not that much).

2) If you want to have a separate sheet in the workbook for each housekeeper, you might want to automate things a bit more - using a VBA macro. It is not hard, but given how you asked the question, you may not want to tackle it. If you do - here is an approach:

1. Create your workbook with a sheet called "MasterSheet": this is where you put all the information
2. Create a separate sheet for each housekeeper - call your sheets "Katie", "Sue", etc. - one for each employee (whether they are on the list for today or not)
3. Add the following code in a "module": from the workbook, press `Alt-F11`, then (in the VBA editor) Insert... Module and paste this code:

```vb
Sub createDailyWorklist()
'
' Update a series of worksheets based on the first ("Master") sheet
'

'
Dim sh As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
  If Not sh.Name = "MasterSheet" Then ' skip first sheet - it is the "master"
  sh.Activate ' select the sheet
  sh.Cells.Clear ' remove old content
  ' set the criteria for the filter:
  sh.Range("A1").Value = "HK" ' column to filter on
  sh.Range("A2").Value = "'=" & sh.Name ' value to find = sheet name (housekeeper name)
                                        ' using the '= to get an exact match (not "starting with")
                                        ' otherwise Jane would get Janet's work too...

  ' there are 43 rooms so we know where the input data range is:
  Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("A1:D44").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=sh.Range("A1:A2"), CopyToRange:=Range("A3:D3"), Unique _
        :=False
  Rows("1:2").Delete   ' get rid of the criteria
  Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit ' make the columns just wide enough
  End If
Next sh

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

When you want to create the work lists, you press `Alt-F8`, then select "createDailyWorklist" from the menu that appears. Click "Run"

Hey presto! You have one sheet for each housekeeper, with the rooms that need doing etc.

Obviously you can modify this to better suit your needs - formatting, number of fields to copy, etc. But I hope this gets you going.